# Is the second "like" indispensable in the sentence "I not only like their language, but like their culture as well"?

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

> I not only like their language, but **like** their culture as well.

Is it right to say "I not only like their language, but their culture as well"?

Can I omit the "like" after "but"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order for it to be grammatically correct consider using the construction **'not only...but (also)'** http://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-tips-for-fixing-%E2%80%9Cnot-only-but-also%E2%80%9D-errors/

- I not only like their language, but also their culture as well.
- I not only like their language, but their culture as well.
- I not only like their language, but I also like their culture as well.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123795/how-to-use-the-not-only-but-also-construction - A duplicate of this question.